# Customize specific UIBarButtonItem in Storyboard on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

For my iOS 7 app, I have a UIToolbar holding a set of UIBarButtonItems, and for a particular item I want to have a customized appearance.

I would like to just drop the item on the storyboard, and specify its class, without acting on the UIToolbar via code. One option is to use appearance, but unfortunately it results in altering all UIBarBUttonItem.

Some old SO post suggest to subclass UIBarButtonItem and use drawRect, and this would be the ideal solution, but unfortunately such method seems to be not getting called at all.

Answer (score 1):

I know your issue is most likely resolved by now, but with Xcode 6, you can now do exactly as you want!

Xcode 6 allows the usage of the macros `IB_DESIGNABLE` and `IBInspectable` to customize what you can change in the inspector in Interface Builder!

Simply define `IBInspectable` before the type declaration of a property (in the .h) to expose that property to IB, then set it.

If you define `IB_DESIGNABLE` prior to the `@interface`, you'll also be able to see your changes to that custom property *live* in IB!

The following example should provide what you want to do, live in IB in Xcode 6:

#### MyBarButtonItem.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE @interface MyBarButtonItem : UIBarButtonItem

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBInspectable UIImage *backgroundImage;

@end
```

#### MyBarButtonItem.m

```
#import "MyBarButtonItem.h"

@implementation MyBarButtonItem

-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage {
    [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal
                  barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

-(UIImage *)backgroundImage {
    return [self backgroundImageForState:UIControlStateNormal
                              barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

@end
```

Slight disclaimer on the above code: For obvious reasons, this defines the background image *only* for the bar metrics and control state hardcoded.

See the below documentation from Apple for a more visual example:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH41-SW1

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to set the image using [UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] so that appearance proxy tinting won't occur, and you can control the button images.

Unfortunately I don't see that this can be done via XIB ... but if you can get at the button via code, do this:

```
[myBarButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourButtonImage"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where myBarButton is your UIBarButtonItem, and yourButtonImage.png is your bar button image.  This image will appear un-tinted.

Comment: Well, infact I was looking for a way to subclass and call something like [self setImage:...] but seems there's no way

Comment: you should be able to do this by overriding initWithFrame and initWithCoder?

Comment: Uhm...by overridding such methods it seems to work, but, any idea about why for UIBarButtonItem placed on a UIToolbar I cannot set a its background image ? I mean a background image with text on top, set via setBackground... appearance. The same UIBarButtonItem placed on a UINavigationBar it is instead fully customizable with appearance.